# Richardson's theorem for constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

It's known that there is no algorithm for deciding for any elementary function is it identically zero or not (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem ).

But if I consider only constants - is there some algorithm for deciding for any constant expression composed from elementary functions (e. g. $\ln (\sin 1 - \tan (\pi^2))$), is it equal to zero or not?

Comment: For constants? Just evaluate them. You can use some heuristics, like $e^x \neq 0 \forall x$.

Comment: @Newb, computers use only finitely much memory. Real numbers don't.

Comment: Try deciding whether $\tan p - q = 0, p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$. I'm sure that this number can be made arbitrarily small. How will a computer decide if you can't?

Comment: Also there are expressions like $\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}} - 1$ (it's actually zero).

Comment: If no one can answer it here, should it be posted to Math Overflow?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: Just to make clear, decidability of equality between real-valued expressions has nothing to do with the magnitude of their difference. You may want to look up Turing machines to learn about decidable sets.

Comment: @user21820. The magnitude of their difference is relevant if you just hope to evaluate the expression numerically.

Comment: @user21820. It was 2 years ago, but I'm quite sure that my second comment was a continuation of my reply to Newb.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: Ahhh that makes complete sense. Then sorry my comments are irrelevant.

Comment: I you think that this question will find more response on MO, I may try to post it there.

Comment: Yes I think you should post it there and put a link in your question here. I'm interested to know the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The page you cite eventually (at least as of 30 July 2015) links to an answer to your question about [decidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers).

- An algebraic expression is decidable.  This is also the [Tarski-Seidenberg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Seidenberg_theorem).
- Algebraic expressions plus $\exp$ are decidable if [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) holds.  Otherwise, this is unknown.  See [Tarski's exponential function problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_exponential_function_problem).
- Throw in sine and determining whether the constant expression vanishes is undecidable.  (This can be linked to the undecidability of models of the integers (a la Godel's Incompleteness Theorems) via the zeroes of $\sin (\pi k)$ for any integer $k$.  See [Hilbert's Tenth Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) and [Matiyasevich's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matiyasevich%27s_theorem#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem).)  Sine isn't critical; any (real-)periodic function would do.

[Edit:]  Following thinking about comments:  In fact, any function with a (real-)periodic level set (with positive minimal period) would do.  Every non-empty level set of all six trig functions qualify.  The easy case, for a warm-up, is to consider a function with a periodic discrete level set.

Comment: Your answer is too vague on the third point. Can you at least give an outline of why the undecidability has to do with the periodicity?

Comment: @user21820 : I did.  The zeroes of $\sin \pi k$ are the integers.

Comment: That's obvious. What is vague is why undecidability of statements over PA implies undecidability of constant expressions involving $\sin$ and $\pi$. Constant expressions do not have quantifiers.

Comment: @user21820 : The OP is answered.  Sounds like you have a follow-on question.  That's what the "Ask Question" link is for.  Alternatively that's what all the embedded references are for.

Comment: @EricTowers : $\:$ I asked that as "a follow-on question." $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer : Why did you not link to it in your comment here?  For anyone who should land here in the future:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382945/  .

Comment: Uh, I completely forgot about that part. $\:$ The more recent question is [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/223452/5810). $\;\;\;\;$